# Streaming music - release memory

Tags: javascript

I'm building a site for streaming online radiostations at http://bigups.dk using jplayer.

The stream causes the browser to build up memory until no memory is left on the client. Is there any way to release this memory via javasript?

Comment: Its most likely an issue with the browser; what browsers have you tested it against?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the qucik reply guys. I have only testet it in IE 7/8. And since Web Logic did not experience any problems, I will start testing in other browsers and other systems.

Comment: Yeah, IE is pretty (in)famous for its memory leak problems. Good luck with that.